# How to identify whether a set of events (or time intervals) overlap with each other in a PostgreSQL database

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

We are given a dataset which has id, start and endpoint for each event. Our task is to identify whether a given event overlaps or not with any other event. I have tried to find a solution using a temporary table, multiple joins and case conditions. It would be great if people can share a more efficient and concise way of solving this problem. Here is the [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/aff02/3) to solutions.

Input:

```
id  Start_date  End_date

1   2019-01-01  2019-01-31
2   2019-01-15  2019-01-17
3   2019-01-29  2019-02-04
4   2019-02-05  2019-02-10
```

Final output:

```
id       Overlap
1        True
2        True
3        True
4        False
```

Comment: Please specify the database. Sybase, PostgreSQL, H2?

Comment: Thanks, I made the required change.

Comment: Note that in Postgres you can prevent inserting overlapping rows, so you wouldn't need to check that later

Answer (score 3):

In standard SQL, you could do this with a correlated subquery:

```
select
    t.id,
    case 
        when exists (
            select 1
            from mytable t1
            where 
                t1.id <> t.id
                and t1.start_date <= t.end_date 
                and t1.end_date  >= t.start_date
        ) 
        then 'true'
        else 'false'
    end overlap
from mytable t
```

The correlated subquery introduced by the `exists` condition checks if another record has a date range that overlaps the current record; some databases have built-in functionalities for this (namely, Postgres has the `overlaps` operator).

Some database also support direct evaluation of conditions as booleans (or `0/1` numbers): in this case you do not need the `case` expression, you can directly put the `exists` condition in the `select` list.

---

**Edit**: in Postgres, which was finally tagged, the query gets simpler:

```
select
    t.id,
    exists (
        select 1
        from mytable t1
        where 
            t1.id <> t.id
            and (t1.start_date, t1.end_date) overlaps (t.start_date, t.end_date)
    ) overlap
from mytable t
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/aff02/4)

Comment: Please note that the `OVERLAPS` operator considers two adjacent ranges as "non overlapping".

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a cumulative `max()` and `min()`:

```
select t.*,
       (prev_ed >= start_date or next_sd <= end_date) as has_overlap
from (select t.*,
             max(end_date) over (order by start_date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_ed,
             min(start_date) over (order by start_date rows between 1 following and unbounded following) as next_sd
      from t
     ) t;
```

This uses window functions to get the maximum end date *before* a given row -- ordered by the start date.  And to get the minimum start date *after* a given row with the same ordering.

It then calculates overlaps by comparing these values to the values in the row.